# Table repeating bug - need old FF versions

Tags: html, firefox, printing, html-table

Where's the best place to get an older version of Firefox?

I have a printed page, and this has a table on it. If the table wraps onto a second page, the table bordering is lost on any page after the first.

This is a legacy page and I cannot believe no one would have complained previously, so I am fairly certain its a new bug. Hence I want to test on an older version of Firefox...

The download page doesn't appear to have any links... I need all versions from about 40...

Comment: You can find the archive of all Firefox releases [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/). [This](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/40.0/) is a direct link to Firefox 40.0. Also, if you figure this is a bug, please file one on [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org) .

Comment: Once I have tested on previous versions of Firefox I'll have a better idea of regression and will raise a ticket - don't you worry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dexter - sent this link which is the correct answer: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/